# Centering image that fills a container

Tags: css

I want to center my dynamically generated images (all sifferent size and orientation) in an  container, but that it fills up it's size.

My code is:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mobile-list">
<!-- Thumbnails -->

<li>    
<div class="gal-desc">Egy halott énekei</div>   

<a href="http://www.baksagaspar.com/wp-content/gallery/print/ehe-borito-sm_0.jpg" alt="Egy halott énekei" title="&lt;strong&gt;Egy halott énekei&lt;/strong&gt; by Mind-járt" rel="shadowbox  [set_2]">
<img src="http://www.baksagaspar.com/wp-content/gallery/print/thumbs/thumbs_ehe-borito-sm_0.jpg" alt="Egy halott énekei">
</a>

</li>

<li>    
<div class="gal-desc">Technoids</div>   
<a href="http://www.baksagaspar.com/wp-content/gallery/print/technoids-cover-sm_0.jpg" alt="Technoids" title="&lt;strong&gt;Technoids&lt;/strong&gt; by Mind-járt &amp; Friends" rel="shadowbox  [set_2]">
<img src="http://www.baksagaspar.com/wp-content/gallery/print/thumbs/thumbs_technoids-cover-sm_0.jpg" alt="Technoids">
</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.mobile-list li a { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-list li a img { 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Since this is for mobile browsers, it can be CSS3 solution or even jQuery.

Comment: The images are exactly the size you set - width: 145px; height: 145px;

Comment: yes, but it stretches to either dimension is larger, if I set it to fixed size

Answer (score 0):

The images are exactly the size you set -

```
.mobile-list li a { 
    width: 145px;
    height: 145px;
}
```

You can change those values to change the size of your images.

As far as centering goes - I have no idea what you want to center - the whole list, or the a tags in the li tags... more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
.mobile-list li a img { 
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

so it scales to fit its parent width proportionally

Comment: it gives me the same results like before, but still not centered to the container <a>

Answer (score 0):

CSS :

```
.img{
margin:50%;
}
```

Here You Go !

Comment: unfortunately it puts the top left edge of the img to the center

Answer (score 0):

to make it fill the whole container and resize with it go ahead and try this:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.mobile-list li{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.mobile-list li a img { 
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not possible with css I better make the thumbnails to a fixed square dimension...

Thanks for your effort.

Comment: you can give comment below the answer